concurrent celery tasks processing with sequential processing of unique route key
I'm working on a mediator service that receives events from multiple monitoring systems, correlates contextual information, and triggers subsequent messages/actions.
I.e. receive event[topic_key] > look up in ticket system of existing/open {log if exists & open else create new issue} > fire off subsequent tasks
The ticket system acts as a simplistic flood control mechanism to prevent duplicate actions/notifications for unique event[topic_key]
I need to be able to handle a large number of event[topic_key] concurrently, but need to avoid creating duplicate new ticket issues when multiple events with the same topic_key are received in a very short window of time. My celery workers are set to scale and need to be in order to avoid delaying event processing.
Anyone experienced with tuning the celery broker (rabbitmq currently, but can change if needed) exchanges, queues, and/or route_key etc. to provide a "unique concurrence" task execution where workers can scale and process tasks concurrently for unique topic_keys, but prevent concurrent task execution for multiple occurrences of the same topic_key in the task queue? I.e. utilizing a topic exchange.
Our topic keys are expansive (1000's), so using simple static/explicit queues (alone) names isn't feasible.
I can achieve this by other less elegant means, but curious if there are native capabilities with celery/rabbitmq that might cover this scenario.
